# R: Mimicking the with function within a Function

Tags: r, function

I have been working on this for a few hours and I am pretty much stuck.  I would like a function that acts like the `with` function but allows me to generate new variables in my `data.frame` using other variables in the `data.frame` or external values.

```
MYDATA <- data.frame(a1=rnorm(5), a2=rnorm(5))

dg <- function(svar, exp, tempdata="MYDATA") {
  tempdata <- get(tempdata)
  tempdata[svar] <- with(tempdata, eval(substitute(exp)))
  return(tempdata)
}

MYDATA
#         a1       a2
#1   0.07113  0.84302
#2  -0.46902 -1.12064
#3   1.01703  0.62591
#4   1.13271  0.24405
#5  -0.24867 -0.02474
```

Ideally it would do the following:

```
dg("b",a1+a2)
#         a1       a2       b
#1   0.07113  0.84302  0.9141
#2  -0.46902 -1.12064 -1.5897
#3   1.01703  0.62591  1.6429
#4   1.13271  0.24405  1.3768
#5  -0.24867 -0.02474 -0.2734
```

Thanks for your consideration!
Francis

Comment: Are you looking for `within`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line of the function body should be:

```
tempdata[svar] <- eval(substitute(exp), tempdata)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Awesome! I did not realize I was so close!